# How to write and read dynamic arrays from binary file

Tags: c, struct, binaryfiles, dynamic-arrays

I have this struct

```
    struct _recipe
{
    char name[50];
    char** ingredients;
    char diff[12];
    int time;
    int calories;
    char** procedure;   
} recipe;
```

And I want to copy all the data inside a binary file.
First of all I've allocated dynamically the memory for both the ingredients and procedure and I have written all I needed. But then I need to write all in a binary file. I know that they are both pointers, so this mean that if I use

```
fwrite(&recipe,sizeof(recipe),1,fbr);
```

I'll write inside the file the address and not the actually value which is I need. I've tried writing every single field of the struct inside the file this way

```
    fwrite(recipe.name,sizeof(recipe.name),1,fbr);

    fgets(recipe.ingredients[j],30,stdin);
            strcpy(buff,recipe.ingredients[j]);
            len = strlen(buff);
            fwrite(buff,sizeof(recipe.ingredients[0]),len,fbr);

   fwrite(recipe.diff,sizeof(recipe.diff),1,fbr);
   fwrite(&recipe.time,sizeof(recipe.time),1,fbr);
   fwrite(&recipe.calories,sizeof(recipe.calories),1,fbr);

    fgets(recipe.procedure[i],1000,stdin);
            strcpy(buff,recipe.procedure[i]);
            len = strlen(buff);
            fwrite(buff,sizeof(recipe.procedure[0]),len,fbr);
```

I'm not sure it's the right way but I tried putting the string inside an other one and then copying it on the file. The problem is, I'm not sure it worked because I don't know what kind of command should I put for reading all the values I stored. With the name of course it worked, I didn't have problems with that but then when I was about to read the ingredients I blocked myself because I wrote the value inside an other string and I don't know what lenght should I put in reading. Maybe I'm missing something, probably I'm messing with writing in the first place but I don't know what to do at this point.

Comment: you can look at the contents of the file with a utility like the linux command `od -c`.  For the ingredients, you would need to change the `sizeof` operator, since it won't tell you how big the ingredient string is.  You would want to write out the entire string plus a null terminator so you know when the next ingredient begins.  Same with the `procedure` fields.  You should also look for posts about marshalling and unmarshalling data structures.

Comment: @bruceg Since I don't have linux I guess i can't read them unless I open them inside the program.  Anyway, the write line would become like this? `fwrite(buff,sizeof(buff),1,fbr)`? Sorry I'm a bit confused about this, also with reading procedure

Comment: If you are using windows, you can install `cygwin` and get the cool linux tools.  Consider your call `fwrite(buff,sizeof(recipe.ingredients[0]),len,fbr);`. You will write out len elements, where len is the result of strlen.  That means, you haven't written out a null terminator.  You also want to write out each ingredient, not just the first one.  How do you tell in your struct how many ingredients or procedures there are?

Comment: @bruceg so I should write `fwrite(buff, sizeof(recipe ingredients[i], len,fbr)` where len is strlen plus the null terminator?

Comment: Yes. That seems correct to me.  That way you will have written out the null terminator.  Then when you read back in your file, you can tell the end of each ingredient or procedure by the null terminator.  Also, I misread your code a bit.  Your variable buff  is the ingredient or procedure as appropriate for the loop.

Comment: @bruceg sorry, I didn't understand the part about the variable buff

Comment: I just meant that your code is OK.  I didn't see that you were updating buff each time.

Comment: @bruceg okay I see... But when I want to read all the struct element by element and I want to read ingredients and procedures I need to put the instruction `fread(buff, sizeof(recipe.ingredients),len,fbr)`? But since it's another program how I am supposed to understand the size and the length?

Comment: I just realized that your sizeof is actually wrong.  `sizeof(recipe.ingredients[i])` is going to tell you how big a `char *` is, which isn't what you want.  You just want the size of a char.  So, your fwrite should be like this: `int num_elements = fwrite(recipe.ingredients[i],sizeof(char),len,fbr);`

Comment: @bruceg oh I see, so this would work for writing, thank you

Comment: @bruceg you use num_elements to understand the length of the array?

Comment: The num_elements tells us if fwrite was successful in writing out what you requested.

Comment: You should have **serialized** your data when writing the binary file, so that it could be read back in a portable way. How compilers handle `struct` padding is completely *implementation defined*, meaning a binary file saved by writing out an array of struct on one machine is not guaranteed to be readable on another. That said, for a learning exercise, you should be able to write an array of struct to a binary file and then read it back in the same way on the same machine.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin So if I create an array of struct I can write it all at once?

Comment: Yes and NO (like that?). Yes if all members of your struct can be written, but note my caution, padding can be different between compilers. No because you have pointers to pointers. Writing an address to your data file makes no sense. The address will be different when it is read. This is why you write (or use) a serialization routine that provides a method of writing the data to the file in a manner that allows it to be read back without those problems. For instance writing the number of `ingredients/procedures` and the size of each would allow them to be written and read.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this to write out your recipe:

```
    fwrite(recipe.name,sizeof(recipe.name),1,fbr);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_ingredients; i++) {
            int len = strlen(recipe.ingredients[i]) + 1;
            int num_elements = fwrite(recipe.ingredients[i],sizeof(char),len,fbr);
            printf("wrote %d elements for %s\n", num_elements, recipe.ingredients[i]);
    }
    fwrite(recipe.diff,sizeof(recipe.diff),1,fbr);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_procedures; i++) {
            int len = strlen(recipe.procedure[i]) + 1;
            int num_elements = fwrite(recipe.procedure[i],sizeof(char),len,fbr);
            printf("wrote %d elements for %s\n", num_elements, recipe.procedure[i]);
    }
```

You also need to write out the calories and time of course.  I would also do this before reading anything into the struct:

```
memset(&recipe, 0, sizeof(struct _recipe));
```

If you use fprintf to write out the calories and time with a `\n` for the separator, your recipe file would look like this:

```
$ od -c recipe.bin
0000000   m   u   f   f   i   n   s  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000020  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
*
0000060  \0  \0   f   l   o   u   r  \0   s   u   g   a   r  \0   e   g
0000100   g   s  \0   v   a   n   i   l   l   a  \0   n   u   t   s  \0
0000120   n   o       d   i   f   f  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0   m   i   x  \0
0000140   b   a   k   e  \0   r   e   s   t  \0   6   0  \n   2   5   0
0000160  \n
```

Comment: Could you explain why do I need memset before reading anything from the struct? Also isn't fprintf used only on text files?

Comment: If you don't do a memset, you will print out random garbage characters after the end of your recipe name.  This way, you get all zero characters.  `fprintf` should work on a binary file.  But, you could continue to use fwrite.  I just used fprintf to make the file contents easier to read.

Comment: I see, but what about the number of ingredients and number of procedures? I don't know it before writing it

Comment: also, the reading would be simply `fread(&recipe, sizeof(recipe), 1,fbr) ` or do I need to read every single value each time?

Comment: No.  You can't read like that.  Imagine overlaying the struct on top of the binary file I pasted above.  The recipe struct's ingredients member is a `char **`. So, you will need to read in all the ingredients to find out how many there are, and then allocate the ingredients array.  Once the ingredients array is allocated, then you can set each point in the array to point to the strings that you have read in.  An alternative is to write out a file header that specifies how many ingredients and procedures there are in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can design a simple storage `protocol` for writing/reading.

For example:

```
| struct recipe | t l v | t l v | ... | t l v | struct recipe | t l v | ... | t l v |

|<-      a complete struct recipe data      ->|


| description | t(ype) | l(ength) | v(alue)|
| ingredient  | i      | strlen() | string |
| procedure   | p      | strlen() | string |
| data end    | e      | 0        | <null> |
```

Read a recipe data:

```
1. Read a struct recipe.
2. Read a t, t=='i' -- go (3.), t=='p' -- go (4.), t=='e' -- go (5.).
3. Read a l, then read a string whose length is l as an ingredient. Go (2.).
4. Read a l, then read a string whose length is l as a procedure. Go (2.).
5. Finish.
```

Write a recipe data:

```
1. Write a struct recipe.
2. Write ingredients to `i strlen(ingredient) ingredient` one by one.
3. Write procedures to `p strlen(procedure) procedure` one by one.
4. Write `e 0`.
5. Finish.
```

Pseudo code: (just a demo, please design your own `protol-`)

```
void write_recipe(recipe *r, FILE *fp)
{
    fwrite(r, sizeof(recipe), 1, fp);
    // ...
    for ()
    {
        sprintf(buff, "i %5d %s", strlen(r->ingredients[i]), r->ingredients[i]);
        fwrite(buff, strlen(buff), 1, fp);
    }
    sprintf(buff, "e 0");
    fwrite(buff, strlen(buff), 1, fp);
    //...
    for ()
    {
        sprintf(buff, "p %5d %s", strlen(r->procedure[i]), r->procedure[i]);
        fwrite(buff, strlen(buff), 1, fp);
    }
    sprintf(buff, "e 0");
    fwrite(buff, strlen(buff), 1, fp);
    // ...
}

void read_recipe(FILE *r, FILE *fp)
{
    fread(r, sizeof(recipe), 1, fp);
    // ...
    while (true)
    {
        fread(&t, sizeof(char), 1, fp);
        if (t == 'e')
        {
            // ...
            break;
        }
        fread(buff, sizeof(char), 7, fp);
        sscanf("%d", &len);
        fread(buff, sizeof(char), len, fp);
        buff[len] = 0;

        ingredient = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
        strcpy(ingredient, buff);
        // ...
    }
    // ...
    while (true)
    {
        fread(&t, sizeof(char), 1, fp);
        if (t == 'e')
        {
            // ...
            break;
        }
        fread(buff, sizeof(char), 7, fp);
        sscanf("%d", &len);
        fread(buff, sizeof(char), len, fp);
        buff[len] = 0;

        procedure = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
        strcpy(procedure, buff);
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't complete understand your answer